# From dataFrame to grouped JSON in R

Tags: r, jsonlite

I have a data frame in R:

```
ID   var1  var2 
1    12    Name1
1    13    Name4
2    13    Name2
3    14    Name3
```

and i wish to transform in json grouping the ones that have the same ID:

```
{
"group":
[
{"ID" : 1, "var1": 12, "var2": "Name1" },
{"ID" : 1, "var1": 13, "var2": "Name4" }
]
},
{
"group":
[
{"ID" : 2, "var1": 13, "var2": "Name2" }
]
},
{
"group":
[
{"ID" : 3, "var1": 14, "var2": "Name3" }
]
}
```

I also want to save each group on a JSON file, so, for the example above, I will have three JSON files

But I can't figure out a way to do this, neither to mount the JSON as I want nor to save each group separately on a JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `jsonlite`

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
lst1 <-  map(split(df1, df1$ID), toJSON)
names(lst1) <- paste0('group', names(lst1))
toJSON(lst1)
```

Comment: I tested with the dataFrame:
```df1 <- data.frame("CPF" = c(1,1, 2), "accountNumber" = c(1843320, 1843321,  1218514) , "coop" = c(116, 116, 116),
           "statement" = c("a","a", "a"),  "brand" = c("Name","Name1","Name2")) ```
And the result did not grouped the ones wth the same ID and also the name is 'group", "group.1" and "group.2", but i have to have just "group" on all names. Do you have any idea on how to change your code? :D 
And thanks a lot btw :D

Comment: .  @CatarinaNogueira  I showed an optin using the example you provided.  THis is a totally different example

Comment: Here, I don't know which one is the ID and the expectedoutput

Comment: Okay, using the exact example I provided that you added there you can see that the Id "1" is on different groups, but I have to have them together on the same group, sorry if this was no clarity on the question :( .
 Also, the "groups" identifier change its name, and I wish the same name to all, as on my example. Do you have a clue how to change your code to do this? Thanks a lot!! :D

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira  the key elements can have only unique keys.  Otherwise, how you are going to extract the values from the same key when the values are different

Comment: expectedoutput : 
```{"group":
 ["{"ID":1,"var":12,"var2":"Name1"}", "{"ID":1,"var":13,"var2":"Name4"}"]},
  {"group": ["{"ID":2,"var":13,"var2":"Name2"}"]},
  {"group": ["{"ID":3,"var":14,"var2":"Name3"}"]}```

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira  Okay, got it.  Can you check the update

Comment: Ow, thanks! I would never know how to do that! I just don't get why the slashes in front on the quotation marks :)

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira  If you do `cat`, it would print without it